# Which is the "correct" way to represent C=AB with \mathbf?

Tags: math-mode

Which is the "correct" way to represent `C=AB` with `\mathbf`?

`\mathbf{C=AB}` or `\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{AB}` or `\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}`

Comment: Probably `\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}`, given that `A` and `B` are separate symbols.

Comment: I guess that the correct way is the way you like, I personally *never* use `\mathbf`, but `\boldsymbol` instead, and I put `\,` between the symbols. I am aware that several users disagree, but I do not think they can call my way of doing thins "wrong". In the end you will never be able to really clarify if, say, typesetting differential `d`s upright (what I do) right or wrong. But I agree with @HenriMenke that `\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}` is better, at the very least you can search for these symbols more easily in your source code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest not to use `\mathbf` explicitly. It would be better to define some meaningful macro name like `\newcommand\matr[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and use it throughout the document. This way the source code becomes more readable and you get the easy way of changing the definition if desired. As for `\matr{A}\matr{B}` vs `\matr{AB}`, I'd say that the former would be better unless **AB** denotes a single matrix (which is very unusual in math).